# Populating different textboxes from different data queries WPF

Tags: wpf

I have 6 textboxes on a page that needs to be populated from 3 different database queries. Assigning the query value directly to the textbox is an option but I would like to know if it is possible to assign the query from the db to something I can relate to the binding of those textboxes.

Example:
Instead of assigning a query to each textbox object on the page load, can I assign each query to a DataContext that I can call in the text binding of the designer(xaml) side?

Comment: You should look into mvvm. Use a viewmodel, bind the textboxes to public properties of it.Then you switch out the source of the data you're reading.

Comment: do you perhaps have any reference to this?

Comment: To mvvm? It's the standard pattern used for wpf development. I'm not so keen on prism for a beginner but this is a good explanation. https://prismlibrary.github.io/docs/wpf/legacy/Implementing-MVVM.html my attempts at introductory samples: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31915.wpf-mvvm-step-by-step-1.aspx    https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32164.wpf-mvvm-step-by-step-2.aspx